# How to create linux users via my own GUI application in Python?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, gtk

I want to write GUI aplication for creating linux users in pyGTK. In linux console it's not a problem, because of the commands `useradd` and `adduser`, but I don't know how to do that via GUI application?

I want to create GUI form with 3 entries (first "name", second "password", third "confirm password") and button "add". I don't know how to send variable with password to `useradd` and `adduser` commands. What option should I use? Or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call something like

```
useradd -m -p PASSWORD
```

where `PASSWORD` is what you get as a result of [`crypt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) function defined in `unistd.h`.

As you've found out yourself, in the case of Python it looks like this

```
import os 
import crypt 

password ="testpassword"
encPass = crypt.crypt(Password,"salt")
os.system("useradd -p "+encPass+" someuser ")
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to edit those files directly.  It's much safer and easier to use adduser or useradd.

Comment: thank you very much! I also found a ready python code:

    `import os
    import crypt
    
    password ="testpassword" 
    encPass = crypt.crypt(Password,"22")
    os.system("useradd -p "+encPass+" someuser ")`

from: [link](http://shutupsquare.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-use-python-script-to-add-users-to-linux-machine-with-useradd-including-password/)

Thanks and greetings!